# Add and modify JSON object using jq

Tags: shell, sed, jq

Sample JSON Input:

```
 {  
"Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowFullAccess",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::XXXX:user/test",
          "arn:aws:iam::XXXX:root"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::test-dev-cognito-settings-us-west-2/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotLike": {
          "aws:userId": [
            "AZASDASDSADA"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected JSON Output:

```
  {  
"Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowFullAccess",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::XXXX:user/test",
          "arn:aws:iam::XXXX:root"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::test-dev-cognito-settings-us-west-2/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotLike": {
          "aws:userId": [
            "AZALEA",
            "Hello"
          ]
        }
      }
},
{
  "Sid": "AllowForSpecificLambda_jdtest",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": "AROAIBA5TVJCIN3OCE2YI"
  },
  "Action": "s3:Get*",
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::oppscience-dev-cognito-settings-us-west-2",
    "arn:aws:s3:::oppscience-dev-cognito-settings-us-west-2/*"
  ],
  "Condition": {
    "StringNotLike": {
      "aws:userId": [
        "AZA"
      ]
    }
  }
 ]
}
```

Pardon me i have done some syntax mistake in the json tags. 
All i want is inside my statement array object i want to add new object + modify existing object.
I am adding new JSON object using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/). Below is my code snippet which is working fine.

```
jq '.Statement[.Statement| length] |= . + {
 "Sid": "AllowForSpecificLambda",
 "Effect": "Allow",
 "Principal": {
    "AWS": [
        "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXX:role/lambda_allow_pretoken_generation"
    ]
   },
 "Action": "s3:Get*","Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::test-XXXX-cognito-settings-'$region'"

        ]}' test.json > test-1.json
```

I am addin new value in my JSON array using below code snippet.

```
jq '.Statement[] 

| select(.Sid == "Test") 
.Condition.StringNotLike."aws:userId"[.Condition.StringNotLike."aws:userId"| length] 
|= . + "Hello"' test.json
```

How can i do this two things in single command?

Thanks

Comment: it would be better if you posted the initial json data and the final expected result

Comment: Why tag this with `sed` when you want to `do this two things in single command` and the command you're using is `jq`?

Comment: The given desired output does not have anything with "Test" or "Hello" in it, so it's unclear where the "new value" is supposed to go.

Comment: @peak I have added the desired "Hello" that should be appended in output. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of the task does not seem to match the given input and output, but the following should get you on your way, as it illustrates the piece you seem to be missing -- that is, to combine the two operations, simply combine them into a pipeline (i.e., using `|`).

Another key point is that it is advisable to pass in parameters (such as `$region` in the present case) as arguments to the jq program.

#### program.jq

```
  .Statement += [ 
    {
     "Sid": "AllowForSpecificLambda",
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
            "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXX:role/lambda_allow_pretoken_generation"
        ]
       },
     "Action": "s3:Get*","Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::test-XXXX-cognito-settings-" + $region

            ]}
        ]
  | .Statement[0].Condition.StringNotLike."aws:userId" += ["Hello"]
```

#### Invocation

Assuming you want `$region` to have some value, say "REGION":

```
jq --arg region REGION -f program.jq test.json
```